# UISegmentedControl deselect / reset after view disappears

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to fix a small bug. I have an `UISegmentedControl` that stays showing user interaction if I navigate back while pressing a segment (without releasing the finger which is selecting the segment from the screen):
[image]

I tried to deselect the segment on `viewWillDisappear` but I doesn't make a difference. Any ideas on how to reset the state of the `UISegmentedControl`?

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    fixedPositionSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControl.noSegment
    fixedPositionSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
}
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Edited with my `viewWillDisappear` function

Comment: removed  `fixedPositionSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0`

Comment: I want the selection to fall back to the first segment (0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in this specific case (leaving the screen while touching the control) the segmented control's `touchesEnded` / `touchesCancelled` functions do not get called. So you could cancel the touch programmatically:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    segmentedControl.touchesCancelled(Set<UITouch>(), with: nil)
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
}
```

Subclassing `UISegmentedControl` might even be the cleaner (but maybe oversized) approach:

```
class SegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    // property to store the latest touches
    private var touches: Set<UITouch>?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        self.touches = touches
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        self.touches = touches
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        self.touches = nil
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
        self.touches = nil
    }

    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        // cancel pending touches when the view is removed from the window
        if window == nil, let touches = touches {
            touchesCancelled(touches, with: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

With that approach you can simply reset the index in `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
}
```

Comment: Great approach.  `segmentedControl.touchesCancelled(Set<UITouch>(), with: nil)` was exactly what I was looking for. Kudos for your `SegmentedControl` as well!